# Pop up not sticking with save text

Tags: css, responsive-design

I've made custom pop over/speech box using boostrap pop over class in plain HTML.

**Issue:** Pop over dosen't seem to stick with the action text *Save Records* when I change output box alignment.

I tried by changing the position but didn't work.

```
 <div class="popover fade bottom in" role="tooltip" style="top: 17.5938px; left: 0; display: inline-table;width: 36%;padding: 0px;text-align: center;border-radius: 0px;padding-bottom: 5px">
            <div class="arrow" style="left: 50%;"></div>
            <h3 class="popover-title" style="display: none;"></h3>
            <div class="popover-content">
                <p>Are you sure you wish to save the records?</p>
                <div style="display:inline-flex">
                    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-save btn-square"  style="background-color:#0076C9;border: none;padding: 5px 25px 5px 25px;margin-left: 0px">Yes</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-default btn-save btn-square"  style="color:#0076C9;padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;margin-left: 8px">Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

FYI: [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mailmrmanoj/Lse8x7qh/)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see how the modal related to the text. The simplest way (as far as I know) would be to create a wrapper, where text & modal would be siblings. Then set `position: relative` to wrapper & `position: absolute` to modal. Also you should change `top` to `bottom` for modal. Here I did a super simple example: https://jsbin.com/yegufisumi/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Updated with jsfiddle pls check @Zdobnov

Comment: @forgottofly Solution is the same, as I wrote above. Now your modal have no idea about the area it should be connected to. Wrapper (your `span`) with `position: relative` will create this area, otherwise modal connects to window.